# Where is Slack after an Ubuntu upgrade?

Tags: slack

I've just upgraded to `VERSION="21.04 (Hirsute Hippo)` and Slack seems to have disappeared from both my Favourites and when I click on `Show Applications`.

It's installed as a Snap package and I can launch it but:

1. how do I return it to `Show Applications` and
2. how do I get the icon back in the Dock (it just shows a grey and white document there instead of the Slack icon)?

Comment: have you tried a `sudo apt reinstall slack`

Comment: Still not in Show Applications